# BASH escape less than < with variables in frontoff with awk, need variable and < to search

Tags: linux, bash, console, escaping

how can I escape the "<" character???
And that before a variable. Because I would like to search with grep in a HTML file and need for example the "lxcc1". However, there must always be a "<" because there are also entries with lxcc and then it is no longer unique and it will output lxcc and lxcc1 which must not be.

```
hostserver="lxcc1"
awk -v RS='<tr><td>|</td></tr>' -F '(</?td>)+' -v OFS='\t' 'NF>1{$1=$1; print}' file | grep -i "$hostserver\<"
```

the "file" is a huge long HTML string in one line:

```
<tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\">GR&Uuml;N</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\">lxcc1</td><td colspan=\"1\">W&eic</td><td colspan=\"1\">dac@sber.de</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\">FIN!!</td></tr><tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" title=\"Hintergrundfarbe : Schwarz 100 %\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><p>lxcssthgbr.de</p></td><td colspan=\"1\">Weic</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td></tr><tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" title=\"Hintergrundfarbe : Schwarz 100 %\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><p><a href=\"http://lxdbdvwpr\">lxdbde</a></p></td><td colspan=\"1\">Wic</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td></tr><tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" title=\"Hintergrundfarbe : Schwarz 100 %\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><p><a ref=\"http://lxdcdv.thlrr.de\">lxdober.de</a></p></td><tdcolspan=\"1\">W&uic</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td></tr><tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" title=\"Hintergrundfarbe : Schwarz 100 %\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><p><a href=\"http://lxelasr.dee\">lxls3sruber.de</a></p></td><td colspan=\"1\">W&uumeic</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td></tr><tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\">GR&Uuml;N</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\">lxcc11</td><td colspan=\"1\">W&eic</td><td colspan=\"1\">dac@sber.de</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\">FIN!!</td></tr><tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" title=\"Hintergrundfarbe : Schwarz 100 %\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><p>lxcssthgbr.de</p></td><td colspan=\"1\">Weic</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td></tr><tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" title=\"Hintergrundfarbe : Schwarz 100 %\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><p><a href=\"http://lxdbdvwpr\">lxdbde</a></p></td><td colspan=\"1\">Wic</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td></tr><tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" title=\"Hintergrundfarbe : Schwarz 100 %\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><p><a ref=\"http://lxdcdv.thlrr.de\">lxdober.de</a></p></td><tdcolspan=\"1\">W&uic</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td></tr><tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" title=\"Hintergrundfarbe : Schwarz 100 %\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><p><a href=\"http://lxelasr.dee\">lxls3sruber.de</a></p></td><td colspan=\"1\">W&uumeic</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td></tr><tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\">GR&Uuml;N</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\">lxcc</td><td colspan=\"1\">W&eic</td><td colspan=\"1\">dac@sber.de</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\">FIN!!</td></tr><tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" title=\"Hintergrundfarbe : Schwarz 100 %\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><p>lxcssthgbr.de</p></td><td colspan=\"1\">Weic</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td></tr><tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" title=\"Hintergrundfarbe : Schwarz 100 %\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><p><a href=\"http://lxdbdvwpr\">lxdbde</a></p></td><td colspan=\"1\">Wic</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td></tr><tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" title=\"Hintergrundfarbe : Schwarz 100 %\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><p><a ref=\"http://lxdcdv.thlrr.de\">lxdober.de</a></p></td><tdcolspan=\"1\">W&uic</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td></tr><tr><td class=\"highlight-#000000\" style=\"text-align: right;\" title=\"Hintergrundfarbe : Schwarz 100 %\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"#000000\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><p><a href=\"http://lxelasr.dee\">lxls3sruber.de</a></p></td><td colspan=\"1\">W&uumeic</td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td><td colspan=\"1\"><br /></td></tr>
```

result output is:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

but I see I did something wrong in awk....

Comment: `<` has no special meaning in regular expressions, you don't have to escape it.

Comment: please update the question to show the expected output

Comment: This works fine for me: `hostserver="lxcc1"; grep -i "$hostserver<" file`

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: give me a second a will precise the question

Comment: Regarding `I see I did something wrong in awk.` - the error message you posted starts with `bash`, not `awk`, indicating you did something wrong in bash, not awk. The code you posted doesn't produce that error message though so we can't do much to help you debug whatever code did produce it since we can't see it.

Comment: @DKGermany The file argument to `awk` *must* be a filename, not raw data. I suspect the error has to do with how you're passing that HTML string, but without seeing what you're actually doing that's just a guess. Please make sure that the code you post doesn't leave out the part that's actually causing the problem. See ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DKGermany : maybe it has special parsing rules in German, but ur input line includes `W&eic`, and I couldn't locate in my reference lists what html entity `&eic` maps to.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't escape `<`, try this:

```bash
hostserver="lxcc1"; awk -v RS='<tr><td>|</td></tr>' -F '(</?td>)+' -v OFS='\t' 'NF>1{$1=$1; print}' file | grep -i "$hostserver<"
```